# How to implement text replacement with IHTMLTxtRange?

Tags: internet-explorer, text, replace, mshtml

I'm using an IHTMLTxtRange object instance to replace the current user's selection in the browser.

Today, i came across the following problem. This is my markup:

```
<body><p><a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a></p></body>
```

The user selection (html), as informed by the IHMLTxtRange instance (range), is:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
```

Whenever i execute `range.replaceHTML("test");` the result is:

```
<body><p><a href="http://www.google.com">test</a></p></body>
```

This behavior seems to apply also to scenarios like this:

```
<body><p><b>some text</b></p></body>
```

Can anyone help me to develop a consistent selection replacement strategy? I mean, that text selection works as expected.

Thanks

---

**Update 10/05/2012: Clarified experienced problem**

Coming back now I realize that the problem was not explicited correctly. I expected to replace the whole string `<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>` with `test`. Instead, the `innerText` of the anchor was replaced, leaving it´s markup untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution Review**

Finally, I've found the answer to this one through the [Internet Explorer Extension Development](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieextensiondevelopment/threads) forums.

As a side note, from the [the answer I received](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/b75be435-72b2-42f6-a947-62a4d2dba01a), this problem also seems to happen when using the `pasteHTML` method on an `IHTMLTxtRange` object. There's even a [closed issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/569921/ihtmltxtrange-pastehtml-method-does-not-replace-span-tags) describing this problem in the Microsoft Connect website.

**Workaround**

I fixed the problem, based on the answer I got, by checking whether the current element in the range is an anchor: if that's the case, the parent element of the current element is removed and the desired text is inserted in its place.

I had to do this check also for styling elements: `<B>`, `<I>` and `<FONT>` tags.

Be sure to check the question I got answered for more information.